# Scripted multi-file upload in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, multifile-uploader

I'm trying to develop a Wordpress application that needs to aggregate multiple files from client machines. The files are in a top-level folder with names like "202008010" representing dates. All such folders (in every client machine) have the exact same structure and file-naming conventions.

What is required is that the user clicks on a top-level folder, and the script uploads a standard set of files from inside the folder to the WordPress server (say, 6 files which have the same name in every folder). The file names can be hard-coded in the script. The idea is to reduce 6 separate uploads to a single click of the top-level folder.

Is this at all feasible? Any pointers to how it could be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try "something" to achieve this functionality? I believe js plugin could help to select multiple files, but, there would be a manual process. In my opinion, it would be difficult to auto-select rule-based files from client machine (due to security concerns)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I had suspected that the security sandbox would prevent script-based upload, but had no way to confirm it.